# How to get generic container class of a ParameterizedType in java

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Every questions about the java reflection on generic types I found, were asking about getting parameters of a generic type.
In my case, I have a ParameterizedType and want to get the Generic container class.

For example, suppose a

```
ParameterizedTypeImpl.toString()
```

returns

```
java.util.List<test.Bar>
```

Now I want to get a Class of java.util.List.

It might sound a little wired for you, but I need you to suppose it is what it is!

So what I need is something like

```
 Class cls = ((MagicCast)ParameterizedTypeImpl.mayBeAMagicHere()).someOtherMagic();
 //Now cls is of type List
```

The only way I can think of is to use subString or regex to get java.util.List out of the ParameterizedTypeImpl.toString() and then use class.forName to get the class.
But I don't know how portable it is. Is it possible some versions of java have other implementation for the toString of a ParameterizedTypeImpl?

Is there any better solution than that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`getRawType`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html#getRawType--) should do the trick?

```
Class<?> theClass = (Class<?>) yourParameterizedType.getRawType();
```

The cast should be safe since the docs say that the returned value is *the `Type` object representing the class or interface that declared this type*, but well, no guarantees guaranteed :)

Comment: Thank you man, Now I see I was working with a Type casted version of a ParameterizedType and did not see that little getRawType. "guarantees guaranteed" hell yeah :) So true. But tell this to those fat ass employers and see what happens ;)